# How to check the background-color of an element using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

```
if($(this).css("background-color")==Crimson)
```

is this correct ?  .css("background-color","white")  will change the color, but I don't want to change, I wanna know which color it is.

Comment: The major browsers will always return the background color in `rgb` or `rgba` format older browsers will return the value which was set.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

it works like this

```js
if ($("#notify-9").css('background-color')=="rgb(220, 20, 60)") alert("matched");
```

you need to convert name to red, green, blue components, you might use this tool

http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php

Comment: Subtle detail... when writing rgb() take note of the leading spaces before the second and third value.

Answer (score 5):

Use quotes `""` or `''`:

```
if($(this).css("background-color")=="Crimson")
```

Comment: Note that this will only work in older browser version. New Browsers will return `"rgb(220, 20, 60)"` if `"Crimson"` was set. Try it out: `$("<div>").css("background-color","Crimson").appendTo("body").css("background-color")`

Comment: @micha: Yeah if not set otherwise but background name shows op has set it.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes around the color name as:

```
if( $(this).css("background-color") == "Crimson" )
```

otherwise it is right.

Answer (score 1):

just use below line

```
if($(this).css("background-color")=="crimson")
```

as `css("background-color")` attribute result will be in small letters . so if you will compare with capital obviously it will return false. :) 
Small trick hope that work

Answer (score 0):

Possible answers in JavaScript is like this:

```
if(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("notify-9"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color") == "rgb(220, 20, 60)"){
   alert("matched!");
}
```

// rgb(220, 20, 60) is equal to Crimson