# JQuery Select all p tag with style=background-color

Tags: jquery, css

What I need to do is add CSS to a paragraph tag if it has the style=background-color:#aaddff;

I have the following, but something isn't quite right as the border isn't being added.

Do I need to use element.style or is something completely different?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('p').filter(function () {
         return $(this).css("background-color") === "#aaddff";
        })
        .css("border", "2px solid black");
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>       
    <p class="test" style="background-color:#aaddff;">Hello</p>
    <p class="test" style="background-color:blue;">Hello</p>
    <p class="test" style="background-color:#aaddff;">Hello</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: possibly the dupicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411187/how-to-check-the-background-color-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the background color code of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element)  && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411187/how-to-check-the-background-color-of-an-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).css("background-color")` is returning the `RGB` value of your color, so you must compare that, not the hexadecimal value :

```js
$('p').filter((_, e) => $(e).css("background-color") == "rgb(170, 221, 255)")
  .css("border", "2px solid black");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test" style="background-color:#aaddff;">Hello</p>
<p class="test" style="background-color:blue;">Hello</p>
<p class="test" style="background-color:#aaddff;">Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery returns an RGB value and not a hexadecimal code in the "css" function, as you can see at http://api.jquery.com/css/.

You can use the code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740716/2789759) to convert to hex.